# System-wide Scrollbar Theme

Tags: kubuntu, kde, oxygen

I have Kubuntu 12.04 (KDE 4.8.4). I also have `ubuntu-desktop` installed. I am using the Oxygen, which I like very much except for the scrollbars. I have written a scrollbar theme (based on Gmail scrollbar theme for Firefox). How can I make sure that every window uses my scrollbar theme instead of Oxygen's? I found some CSS files in `/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-3.0/`. Is there something I can edit there?

My scrollbar theme can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/nfXz10P0), if anyone is interested.

Comment: I think `oxygen-gtk` is for rendering gtk apps, so your changes in the specified folder should not affect Qt apps. I would like to know how to change scrollbar color in all applications.

Comment: Oh. in the desktopthemes folder, there is a folder called "Oxygen", but everything in it are svgz files. Do you know what to do with them? They appear to be image/icon files...

Comment: I asked this question [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=107042)

Comment: Ah. Hopefully you'll get an answer. Post a comment if it comes... thanks!